# Keep iPhone webapp loading screen up until another image is loaded

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications

I am making an iPhone webapp and I have the apple-touch-startup-image set, and I have a div in the app with the same image so the rest of my app can finish setting up before displaying.

My problem is once the initial apple-startup image finishes there is a flash before the next image in my div shows up (because the image in the div hasn't loaded yet). So how can I have the image in the div finish loading BEFORE the apple startup image finishes?